# SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I'm currently trying the new Jetpack ViewModel with savedState.

```
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-rc01'
```

I'm using 1 Activity and trying to share 1 ViewModel with 2 Fragments but when I try to start the second fragment I get the error from the title.

This is how I'm calling the ViewModel with the savedInstance:

```
    val repository = (activity?.application as App).getRepository()
    viewModel = activity?.run {
        ViewModelFactory(repository, this, savedInstanceState).create(MainViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

And this is my log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
    at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider(SavedStateRegistry.java:111)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:50)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.create(SavedStateHandleController.java:70)
    at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:67)
    at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:84)
    at com.xxx.yyy.presentation.details.DetailsFragment.onCreate(DetailsFragment.kt:29)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2586)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1197)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1080)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:119)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
```

Looks like it's trying to use a SavedState which was already registered and hence the error? I thought that was the whole point of the library. Can anyone help or point on how to use this passing arguments to the ViewModel and using the savedStateHandle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should never be calling `create` yourself - by doing so, you're not actually using the retained `ViewModel` that is already created, causing the `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory` to attempt to register the same key more than once.

Instead, you should be passing your `ViewModelFactory` to a `ViewModelProvider` instance to retrieve the already existing ViewModel or creating it only if necessary:

```
val repository = (activity?.application as App).getRepository()
viewModel = activity?.run {
    val factory = ViewModelFactory(repository, this, savedInstanceState)
    ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
} ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

If you depend on `fragment-ktx` of version `1.1.0` or higher, you can instead use the [`by activityViewModels`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#activityviewmodels) Kotlin property delegate, which lazily uses `ViewModelProvider` under the hood:

```
val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels {
    val repository = (activity?.application as App).getRepository()
    ViewModelFactory(repository, requireActivity(), savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, initially had issues in converting the code to java but it helped in the end.

Comment: Would **SavedState** survive force-killing the app?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - no, saved instance state does not survive force stopping an app. You'd need to persist the data if you want it to survive force stopping.

Comment: @ianhanniballake What does Android documentation mean by: `These values will persist after the process is killed by the system and remain available via the same object`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: As we talked about [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62139420/115145), the documentation is referring to when the process is terminated to free up system RAM.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into the *given key is already registered* error, I did go through [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158737069), [this](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2328) and [this](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2623). But I haven't found anything helpful. In my case, the issue was with Moshi Json Generators.

**File1: VictimViewModel.kt**

```
class VictimViewModel constructor(
  private val searchManager: SearchManager,
) : ViewModel() {

}
```

**File 2: SearchManager.kt**

```
class SearchManager internal constructor(
  private val SearchApi: SearchApi
) {
  fun searchString(token: String): Either<A, B> {
    return searchApi
      .searchString(token)
      .process(
        this::parseResponse
      )
  }
}
```

**File 3: SearchAPI.kt**

```
internal interface SearchApi {
@GET("$BASE_PATH/search_string")
  fun searchString(@Query("search_string") token: String): NetworkEither<SearchResponse>
}
```

**File 4: SearchResponse.kt** (This file has the root cause)

```
data class SearchResponse(
  @Json(name = "suggestions")
  val suggestions: List<String>
)
```

#### What is wrong with the above code?

I forgot to add `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` annotate to `SearchResponse` data class. Which has broken the injection mechanism and started throwing `key is already registered` error while initiating the ViewModel. Error messaging and the actual issue are totally irrelevant. So, it took a while for me to understand the problem.

**Solution:**
Update the File 4: SearchResponse.kt as below

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class SearchResponse(
  @Json(name = "suggestions")
  val suggestions: List<String>
)
```