# Android SavedStateHandle doesn't save in ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel which takes a `SavedStateHandle` parameter.  I am saving a String in there like this:

```java
    private fun saveString(str: String) {
        state.set(KEY_STRING, str)
    }
```

Then I force-close my app and relaunch it, and want to retrieve the saved string like this:

```java
fun getSavedString(): String? {
        return state.get<String>(KEY_String)
    }
```

However, it always returns null.  Any ideas how to use SavedStateHandle correctly?

Comment: "Then I force-close my app" -- how do you do that? If you are swiping the app off of the overview screen, since that destroys the task, the saved instance state also goes away. It seems like the red square button in Android Studio does the same thing. I've had the best luck using `adb`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I'm swiping the app to simulate force-closing.  Wouldn't `SavedStateHandle` save the state for this scenario?

Comment: Nope. That's not unique to `SavedStateHandle` -- the saved instance state `Bundle` is tied to the task, so if the task is destroyed, so is the state.

Comment: In that case I do not understand the advantage of using `SavedStateHandle`. Android doc clearly states: **These values will persist after the process is killed by the system and remain available via the same object.**

Comment: The scenario for saved instance state (whether working with the raw `Bundle` or `SavedStateHandle`) is for when the system terminates the process due to low memory conditions, but the user returns to the app quickly (<30 minutes, last I checked).

Comment: Huh.. This is very confusing, the docs also led me to expect that the values persist across task instances.

Answer (score 2):

*"Then I force-close my app and relaunch it.."*

**I guess you kill the app completely =)**

One of the way for reproducing `saveState` case you need:

1. Enable developers mode and check `Don't keep activities`
2. Process limit -> `No background processes`
3. Send you app in background (`SavedStateHandle` will saved)
4. Restore app from background or tap on the icon of app (`SavedStateHandle` will restored)

Another the easiest way:

1. Send you app in background
2. Tap terminate (Logcat)

[image]

3. Restore app from background or tap on the icon of app

> Also you should use `SavedStateViewModelFactory` if you want to
> receive `SavedStateHandle` in `ViewModel`