# Send intent arguments from bundle to ViewModel using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to send three values to my `UserViewModel` but even if sending the `savedStateHandle`

In my `Activity` I have

```
private val viewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels()
```

Then my `UserViewModel` is :

```
@HiltViewModel
internal class UserViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val myRepo: MyRepo,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {
```

But then this `savedStateHandle` is empty, what I'm missing?

Comment: hi, interesting, this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139420/android-savedstatehandle-doesnt-save-in-viewmodel

Comment: I've tried the Factory stuff and `AssistedInject` but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `@AssistedInject` to do so as follows :

```
internal class UserViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    ...
    @Assisted val name: String,
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
}
```

Then I had to create a `Factory`

```
@AssistedFactory
    interface UserViewModelAssistedFactory {

        fun create(name: String): UserViewModel

    }

class Factory(
        private val assistedFactory: UserViewModelAssistedFactory,
        private val name: String, <-- value you want to pass
    ) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return assistedFactory.create(name) as T
        }
    }
```

Then in the `Activity/Fragment` you have to inject the `AssistedFactory` as follows

```
@Inject internal lateinit var assistedFactory: UserViewModel.UserViewModelAssistedFactory

    private val userViewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels {
        UserViewModel.Factory(assistedFactory, intent.getStringExtra(USER_NAME_ARG).orEmpty())
    }
```

Doing this it should work, but also your solution should work make sure you are sending the intent args correctly because it says is *null* looks like what you are passing is not correct, `savedInstace.keys()` should return everything you passed from your previous `Activity/Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM based on the [Android Architecture guidelines](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture?gclid=Cj0KCQiAkMGcBhCSARIsAIW6d0B8tX1PlkjP6oYVjs4i3knIe_j6s5LCx4wQdtTQjtb2_qfJbepPTZ4aAkeYEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) you can send an event to the viewmodel from your Activity/Fragment once your view is created.

Comment: Yes, but I want to do something like I was doing before with Dagger2 subComponent and Factories

Answer (score 0):

You must add savedStateHandle in AppModule. You want inject savedStateHandle.