# Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger, dagger-hilt

Below is my code, I don't know why there is such a problem, I have pasted the code that may be relevant below.

I don't know that registerSavedStateProvider will be affected by those places.

**CrashLOG**

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
       at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider(SavedStateRegistry.java:111)
       at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:50)
       at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.create(SavedStateHandleController.java:70)
       at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:67)
       at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:84)
       at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:109)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
       at com.xx.getVm
```

**Activity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            val target = XXFragment()
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, target)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
}


override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.putParcelable(xx,xx)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        xx = xx
    }
```

**Fragment**

```
private val vm: XXViewModel by viewModels()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775611/savedstateprovider-with-the-given-key-is-already-registered)